# Creating a Lisp macro that can apply a lambda to a list within a context

Tags: lambda, macros, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

Basically I am trying to write a Common Lisp macro defined as:

```
(defmacro applyfunct (function arguments variables))
```

that applies the function given as the argument `function`, to the argument `arguments` (which is a list of arguments to apply the function to), that, when necessary, uses the variables given to it in the list of lists `variables`. So the return value when it is called with these arguments like this:

```
(applyfunct + (7 5) ((x 1) (y 2)))
```

would be 12, considering that 7+5=12, and the context variable x and y were not needed to apply the function to the arguments. However when it does require the context variables given:

```
(applyfunct (lambda (x y) (+ (* a x) (* y b)) (4 2) ((a 2) (b 4))))
```

it should use these variables if they are needed in the function given to evaluate to return 16, because:

```
(applyfunct (lambda (x y) (+ (* a x) (* y b)) (4 2) ((a 8) (b 1))))
;                    4 2        8 4     2 1    
; (+ (* 8 4) (* 2 1)) => 34
```

hopefully my comments here make clear what I'm trying to do. What I have so far is:

```
(defmacro applyfunct (function arguments variables)
    (let ( ((car (first contents)) (cdar (first contents))
           ((car (second contents)) (cdar (second contents))
```

but I have no idea how to proceed...

```
(apply function arguments)
```

would only work for the first example call where the function is +, not the second function call with the lambda. Am I missing something here? Should I be using ` or #' somehow? Note: I am trying to program as functionally as possible (minimal to no side effects, for example, not using setq). I am also using the CLISP implementation of Common Lisp.

Comment: This looks like an exercise? Generally a macro like that does not look very useful. It can be implemented with a very simple source translation (see the answer of melpomene)

Comment: This is very weird and has little to nothing about application. I'm thinking you perhaps mix `apply` in the implementation and `apply` an a typical `eval` interpreter. In the latter it would be normal to have an argument representing the environment. '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, `apply` would only work for the second example (`lambda`), not `+`.

But remember that you're writing a macro, which can construct program code (such as `(+ 7 5)` or `((lambda (x y) ...) 4 2)`) as needed.

The first step is to make the function call work (ignoring `variables` for now). In Lisp, the syntactic form of a function call is a list whose first element (head) is the function and and whose remaining elements (tail) are the function arguments. This structure can be built e.g. by using `cons`:

```
(defmacro applyfunct (function arguments variables)
    (cons function arguments))
```

Or, using the syntactic sugar of `` ` ``:

```
(defmacro applyfunct (function arguments variables)
    `(,function ,@arguments))
```

(`` ` `` acts like a code template, with `,` marking the spots where variables are to be inserted and `,@` additionally flattening the list.)

Now, to make `variables` work, `let` can be used to provide bindings (as in your code). However, there is no need to destructure `variables` manually; it already has the right shape for a list of `let` bindings:

```
(defmacro applyfunct (function arguments variables)
    `(let ,variables
        (,function ,@arguments)))
```

We can test this macro:

```
(print (macroexpand-1 '(applyfunct (lambda (x y) (+ (* a x) (* y b))) (4 2) ((a 8) (b 1)))))
; by the way, one of the ') is misplaced in your example: ----------^
```

Producing this output:

```
(LET ((A 8) (B 1)) ((LAMBDA (X Y) (+ (* A X) (* Y B))) 4 2))
```

... which is exactly what we want.